# Are there any desktop email clients that are identical to GMail but allow import via IMAP?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, pop3, email-client

I want to consolidate all my emails to 1 gmail account. 1 of the accounts I want to add into Gmail, however, doesn't allow POP3 import or Email Forwarding, so there's no way to get those messages into Gmail webmail. I was wondering if anyone knew of a Desktop Client that has the same/most similar interface as GMail but allows IMAP import. Alternatively, if anyone knows of a WebMail with IMAP import and a similar interface to GMail, that would work also. I am currently using Thunderbird on desktop with a filter that moves messages from all accounts into the Gmail account, but obviously this only works while the software is running.

Comment: Could also be a free server that sucks out emails via IMAP and then forwards them to Gmail or lets Gmail POP3 import them.

Comment: Programs like imapsync can transfer mail in the background automatically.

Comment: Looked like that one cost $. Was hoping for a free solution. And for Windows I should've specified. Could you post directions for free imapsync download/use if it's possible?